# Avoid Duplicate Rows When One Column is Not Unique

Tags: sql, duplicates, unique, distinct

I am creating a query which uses a total of about 20 columns.  I have a lot of records that are duplicates, due to one column being different.  This column is sort of a flag and can only contain a 'Y' or 'N'.  My problem is that if the flag is 'Y', there is also an additional row with the flag of 'N' for the same claim.  How can I only show the rows with 'Y'.  Side note: some of the results will only have an 'N' which is correct, so I cannot use flag = 'Y' in the where clause.

Query:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#HeaderCount') is not null drop table #HeaderCount
Select Distinct 
[MCO Claim ID (ICN)] = c.claimid
,[Header Claim Acceptance Status] = Case When c.reject = 'Y' Then 'X' Else 'A' End
,[Header Claim Source Status] = Case When c.ClaimID not like '%A%' or c.claimid not like '%R%'                                                                           Then 'OR'
                                 When c.claimID like '%A%' Then 'AJ'
                                 When c.claimID like '%R%' Then 'RV' End
,[Header Claim Ever Pended] = Case When ca.Orig_Status = 'PEND' Then 'Y' Else 'N' End 
,[Header Claim Adjudication Payment Status] =  c.Status
,[Member Medicaid ID] = ek.carriermemid
,[LDH Billing Provider ID] = '' --Optional
,[Billing Provider NPI] = p2.NPI
,[Servicing Provider NPI] = p.NPI
,[Header From Date of Service] = cast(c.StartDate as date)
,[Header To Date of Service] = cast(c.EndDate as date)
,[Date Claim Received by the MCO] = cast(c.CleanDate as date)
,[Date Claim Adjudicated by the MCO] = cast(c.adjuddate as date)
,[Date Claim Paid by the MCO] = cast(c.paiddate as date)
,[Billed Charges] = c.totalamt
,[MCO Paid Amount] = c.totalpaid
,c.formtype
,[BillType] = c.FacilityCode + c.BillClassCode
,c.reject
,c.status
into #HeaderCount
from claim c    (NOLOCK)
left join affiliation a2        (NOLOCK)--pay to affiliation
on a2.affiliationid = c.affiliationid
left join dbo.provider p2   (NOLOCK)    --pay to provider
on a2.affiliateid = p2.provid
inner join provider p   (NOLOCK)    --rendering provider
on p.provid = c.provid
inner join claim_audit ca   (NOLOCK)
on c.claimid = ca.claimid
inner join member m     (NOLOCK)
on c.memid = m.memid
inner join enrollkeys ek        (NOLOCK)
on m.memid = ek.memid
and ek.segtype = 'int'
Where c.cleandate between '1/1/2017' and '1/31/2017'
Order By c.claimid
```

I only want to see one row (the 'Y' row) for every [MCO Claim ID (ICN)] that has both a 'Y' and 'N' in the [Header Claim Ever Pended] column.  I think a partition by row number may be the solution?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information or if this doesn't make sense.  I am working on providing sample data as soon as I fix a VPN issue I am experiencing.  Thanks in advance.

Here is some example data:

[MCO Claim ID (ICN)] [Header Claim Ever Pended]

1  15059C063424A1        Y

2  15059C063424A1        N

3  15218C098293A2        N

In the above example, assume all values in every column (not shown) are the same for lines 1 and 2 except column [Header Claim Ever Pended].  I only want to see the 'Y' record, if one exists, for every claimid (not both a Y and N record).  Also, if the [MCO Claim ID (ICN)] doesn't have a 'Y' record, then I want to see the 'N' record.

Answer (score 1):

Add a ROW_NUMBER:

```
with cte as
 ( -- DISTINCT is calulated after ROW_NUMBER
    Select Distinct 
    [MCO Claim ID (ICN)] = c.claimid
    ,[Header Claim Acceptance Status] = Case When c.reject = 'Y' Then 'X' Else 'A' End
    ,[Header Claim Source Status] = Case When c.ClaimID not like '%A%' or c.claimid not like '%R%'                                                                           Then 'OR'
                                     When c.claimID like '%A%' Then 'AJ'
                                     When c.claimID like '%R%' Then 'RV' End
    ,[Header Claim Ever Pended] = Case When ca.Orig_Status = 'PEND' Then 'Y' Else 'N' End 
    ,[Header Claim Adjudication Payment Status] =  c.Status
    ,[Member Medicaid ID] = ek.carriermemid
    ,[LDH Billing Provider ID] = '' --Optional
    ,[Billing Provider NPI] = p2.NPI
    ,[Servicing Provider NPI] = p.NPI
    ,[Header From Date of Service] = cast(c.StartDate as date)
    ,[Header To Date of Service] = cast(c.EndDate as date)
    ,[Date Claim Received by the MCO] = cast(c.CleanDate as date)
    ,[Date Claim Adjudicated by the MCO] = cast(c.adjuddate as date)
    ,[Date Claim Paid by the MCO] = cast(c.paiddate as date)
    ,[Billed Charges] = c.totalamt
    ,[MCO Paid Amount] = c.totalpaid
    ,c.formtype
    ,[BillType] = c.FacilityCode + c.BillClassCode
    ,c.reject
    ,c.status
    from PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.claim c (NOLOCK)
    left join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.affiliation a2     (NOLOCK)--pay to affiliation
    on a2.affiliationid = c.affiliationid
    left join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.provider p2    (NOLOCK)    --pay to provider
    on a2.affiliateid = p2.provid
    inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.provider p    (NOLOCK)    --rendering provider
    on p.provid = c.provid
    inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.claim_audit ca    (NOLOCK)
    on c.claimid = ca.claimid
    inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.member m      (NOLOCK)
    on c.memid = m.memid
    inner join PlanReport_QNXT_LA.dbo.enrollkeys ek     (NOLOCK)
    on m.memid = ek.memid
    and ek.segtype = 'int'
    Where c.cleandate between '1/1/2017' and '1/31/2017'
 ),
cte_with_rn as
 ( -- now apply the ROW_NUMBER
   select *,
      row_number()
      over (partition by  [MCO Claim ID (ICN)]
            order by [Header Claim Ever Pended] desc) as rn -- 'Y' sorts before 'N'
   from cte
 )
select *   -- change to all colujmns except rn
into #HeaderCount
from cte_with_rn 
where rn = 1
Order By claimid
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick...

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY [MCO Claim ID (ICN)] ORDER BY 
[Header Claim Ever Pended] Desc) Row#
Into #temptable
From #HeaderCount

Select *
From #temptable
Where Row# = 1
```

Comment: You don't need to add the partitioning column to order by.